# Rearrange/remove content UI

Tags: nodes, panels

I've seen this on Blackboard and other sites before. How in drupal could have user interaction(UI) with content on each node?

The user should be able to:

-rearrange content on each node with out being a administrator or logged in.
-remove view of content from node and re-populate with more content. The content removed will not be deleted but removed from user view.

I know of panels and I have created panels, but I do not see any UI that allows me to do what I would like to above with panels.

Some help please! Image of what I am talking about. see how user can drag and drop content[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Homebox](https://drupal.org/project/homebox) module.

> Homebox allows site administrators to create dashboards for their users, using blocks as widgets. Blocks in a Homebox page are resizeable, and reorderable by dragging.

Comment: Ill give it a try!

Comment: Only issue is that homebox creates a homebox page,but I'm not looking to put blocks into homebox and display them as page. I want to display the homebox as a block. I see it comes with a custom homebox block, but I do not see any instructions on how to configure this block??